# The company I ordered special trees from put tape directly on the tree, should I remove the tape?

Tags: transplanting

I ordered plants from a catalog, and the "trees" had their names taped on them. Should I let them grow for a while this way (so I know what tree is what), or remove the tape right away?

Comment: I maintain a planting database on my phone so I know what I'm planting and so can track their growth, and don't forget what I've planted.  The DB allows me to add pictures etc.  It's not great but might also work for you.

Comment: In a pinch, an old fashioned folder where you put the labels works too. I usually just snap pictures of plant + label and the ensemble and store them on my computer. And sometimes I enlist my kids to craft "fancy" plant markers, not because I need them, but because it helps them to learn (and pick the right herb for the kitchen).

Comment: The less one uses our newbie technology the better. No technology I know of can replace hands on learning!  Just separates us from learning and success with plants!  If you can't remember a tree YOU planted I am definitely worried!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get any tape, any labels any ribbon OFF the tree!  Prune that tree whilst it is easy to prune (for basic training).  I'll say this again, if that tree has a great heavy clay root ball in relation to the top growth, DO NOT STAKE.  I only stake bare root or damaged trees.  Huge difference in growth and hardiness!!

Comment: I got this dirt from a 20 year old grass compost pile of my neighbors, so it will work VERY WELL this time.

Comment: They trimmed off everything before they shipped also.

Comment: So this 'dirt' from a 20 year old grass compost pile...did these people ever use 'weed 'n feed'?  Or Grub control?  What were their habits with pesticides?  You might be in luck if they were knowledgeable with lawns and pesticides.  What do you mean 'they trimmed off everything' before shipping?  Are these bare  root trees?  How are you planting them?  Bare root trees will need loose staking for 6 months no more.  What are you using for fertilizer?  Watering?  Soil composition of the natural soil? Species of trees, please send pictures.

Comment: I'm not sure if my neighbor did, or not, but it sounded like they use it every year in the garden from what my mom said. They trimmed then to 1-3' roots, except for the balloon flowers, and gladiolus. These are bare root trees similar to what elementry school kids got when smokey came to school. I'm planting them in pots for the first year or so. I'm using epsom salt in a few weeks for the phosphorus, and other nutrients along with coffee grounds for top mulch :D list: http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/5376/how-do-i-properly-colonize-trees-to-work-together-in-a-food-forest

Comment: Epsom salts helps with magnesium but shouldn't be necessary unless your soil is magnesium deficient...coffee grounds are in my opinion, sigh, lame.  To pot bare root trees is actually brilliant.  Please don't use garden soil and it isn't necessary after planting so soon plants from a nursery to fertilize.  Fertilizer DOES not make plants grow faster, healthier unless you do a soil test.  Drainage is critical.  And you are telling me they took ALL THE leaves off the trees?  How the heck are these trees able to produce their own food?  Fertilizer is not food!  Careful adding anything!

Comment: I'm just trying to mimic what I see at the stores when it comes to how to take care of the "baby trees" to take care of them the best way possible.